# Are all amplitudes evaluated on-shell?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, s-matrix-theory, effective-field-theory

In [1] the authors state that for a free scalar theory (eq 7) under field redefinition $\phi\rightarrow a_1 \phi^2 + a_2 \phi^3 + ...$:

> "Once evaluated on-shell, the n-point tree-level amplitudes vanish for
> every n ≥ 3 and, in the classical limit, the field φ has the same
> correlations as a free massless scalar field."

and later [²] the same authors claims that:

> "For the massless theory, the vanishing of all interacting tree- and
> loop-amplitudes was shown on analysing the structure of the S-matrix."

So, are all amplitudes by definiton "evaluated on shell"? I know that external legs are always on-shell, for an amplitude - are the internal lines also always taken on-sell?

[1] https://arxiv.org/abs/1204.3790v1
[2] https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.01837v3